# the proof of existence of solution of stochastic equation

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I am going through the proof of the existence of strong solution of SDE on Brownian motion and Stochastic Calculus by Karatzas and Shreve. However, there is a single line I really cannot see how to conclude. The original theorem is the following: (It is abbreviated)

> Theorem 2.9: Suppose that the coefficients $b(t,x), \sigma(t,x)$ satisfy the global lipschitz and linear growth conditions:
> \begin{align}
> &||b(t,x)-b(t,y)||+||\sigma(t,x)-\sigma(t,y)||\leq K||x-y||\\
> &||b(t,x)||^2+||\sigma(t,x)||^2\leq K^2(1+||x||^2)
> \end{align}
> Then the strong solution of the Stochastic Differential Equation exists. The SDE is $dX_t = b(t,X_t)dt+\sigma(t,X_t)dW_t$.

The proof applies the iteration of approximation. It defines
\begin{align*}
X_t^{(k+1)} = \xi+ \int_0^tb(s,X_t^{(k)}dt + \int_0^t \sigma(s,X_t^{(k)})dW_t
\end{align*}

The question is the following: After some lines it concludes for some constant $L$.
\begin{align}
E[\max_{0\leq s\leq t}||X_s^{(k+1)}-X_s^{(k)}||^2]\leq L\int_0^t E||X_s^{(k)}-X_s^{(k-1)}||^2 ds
\end{align}

Then it says, we iterate this inequality to conclude
\begin{align}
E[\max_{0\leq s\leq t}||X_s^{(k+1)}-X_s^{(k)}||^2]\leq \max_{[0,T]}E||X_t^{(1)}-\xi||^2\cdot \frac{(Lt)^k}{k!}
\end{align}
Why there is a $k!$? It seems keep iterating we only get $\max_{[0,T]}E||X_t^{(1)}-\xi||^2\cdot (Lt)^k$.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Unless mistaken this follows from k integrations over the same argument as :  $$\leq L\int_0^t E||X_s^{(k)}-X_s^{(k-1)}||^2 ds \leq L.\int_0^t E[\max_{0\leq s\leq t}||X_s^{(k)}-X_s^{(k-1)}||^2]ds\leq ...\leq L^k.\int_0^t...\int_0^t E[\max_{0\leq s\leq t}||X_s^{(1)}-\xi||^2]ds$$ the last iterated integrals gives the $t^k/k!$ term unless mistaken

Comment: @TheBridge A lot of thanks!